# Mkdocs "can not display mermaid in the right way"

Tags: mkdocs, mermaid

I try to use this theme plugin to display the graph

> Link:
> https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/diagrams/?h=mermaid

the settings file:

```
- pymdownx.superfences:
      custom_fences:
        - name: mermaid
          class: mermaid-experimental
          format: !!python/name:pymdownx.superfences.fence_code_format
extra_javascript:
  - https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.6.4/dist/mermaid.min.js
```

all i got is this..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exq6R.png)

i dont think it is version problem

Has anyone got any suggestions?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was part of the insiders offer at your time. If you upgrade your mkdocs-material version it should work.

https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/insiders/

Comment: yes sure it is version problem thanks